# How to click on drop-down list which doesn't have id

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How to click on drop-down element which appears after clicking on item:

```
<div class="field loan-selection">
    <label class="field__body">
        <div class="field__label">Nettokreditbetrag
            <!-- -->&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="field__control">
            <div class="Select customSelect has-value Select--single">
                <div class="Select-control">
                    <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-2663001--value">
                        <div class="Select-value">
                            <span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-2663001--value-item">10.000&nbsp;€</span>
                        </div>
                        <div aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-activedescendant="react-select-3--value" aria-disabled="false" class="Select-input" role="combobox" style="border:0;width:1px;display:inline-block" tabindex="0"></div>
                    </span>
                    <span class="Select-arrow-zone">
                        <span class="Select-arrow"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

So, after clicking on element: `id="react-select-2663001--value"`

Drop down menu appears inside this div:

```
<div aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-activedescendant="react-select-3--value" aria-disabled="false" class="Select-input" role="combobox" style="border:0;width:1px;display:inline-block" tabindex="0"></div>
```

And item `aria-activedescendant` change value according number of item inside the list, for example `react-select-3--options-2` or 1 in the end.

So what will be better, can i just change the value for 20 000 for:

```
<span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-2663001--value-item">10.000&nbsp;€</span>
```

or i need to click in some item like: `aria-activedescendan="react-select-3--options-2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q. *How to click on drop-down list which doesn't have id*

A. Its not necessary that all element should have `id` attribute. You can use other attributes to make that unique and locate the same

Now about your problem :

Suppose you clicked on `react-select-2663001--value` and it started showing some dropdown based on your selection

So either you can get all the dropdown option as below

```
List<WebElement> noOfDropdown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[aria-activedescendant^='react-select-3--value']"));
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[aria-activedescendant^='react-select-2--value']"}

Comment: Can't find element like this

Comment: add some pause before getting elements